# Hello - I made a BINANCE bookTicker answer, Pandas. Can someone tell me how to export the table with the result to google sheets?

Tags: pandas, google-sheets, export, google-colaboratory, export-to-excel

''' import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker")

print(type(response.json()))
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response.json()) '''

the result looks like this

```
ETHBTC  0.07536900  0.93840000  0.07537000  10.07200000
LTCBTC  0.00344400  35.44100000 0.00344500  2.39500000
BNBBTC  0.01673800  4.88300000  0.01673900  3.47400000
NEOBTC  0.00040200  1650.58000000   0.00040400  1750.55000000
QTUMETH 0.00161400  66.20000000 0.00161700  99.30000000

OSMOUSDT    1.15100000  250.00000000    1.15500000  151.51000000
OSMOBUSD    1.14900000  291.30000000    1.15500000  21.92000000
HFTBTC  0.00003751  320.90000000    0.00003755  1219.70000000
HFTBUSD 0.62850000  289.90000000    0.62910000  1048.60000000
HFTUSDT 0.62980000  78.60000000 0.63030000  495.20000000
```

I need to save this table in google sheets.
I already have the authorization method for google sheets in google colab

''' from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

sh = gc.create('A new spreadsheet')

## Open our new sheet and add some data.

worksheet = gc.open('A new spreadsheet').sheet1

cell_list = worksheet.range('A1:C2')

import random
for cell in cell_list:
cell.value = random.randint(1, 10)

worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)

## Go to https://sheets.google.com to see your new spreadsheet. '''

please help

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code for saving your data frame as a google spreadsheet.

### code:

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import auth
from google.auth import default
import gspread

response = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker")

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response.json()) #Dataframe from response

#Authentication
auth.authenticate_user()
creds, _ = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
#creating new spreadsheet
sh = gc.create('A new spreadsheet')
#Adding values to spreadsheet from the created dataframe
sh.values_update(
  'sheet1!A1',
  params={
      'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'
  },
  body={
      'values': [df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
  }
)
```

### output:

[image]

### created spreadsheet:

[image]

### References:

https://cyublog.com/articles/python-en/colab-pandas-three-ways-to-save-dataframe-data/
https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/snippets/sheets.ipynb#scrollTo=6d0xJz3VzLOo

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - and for the references I will look into it - so far in my colab I get this error

Comment: '<ipython-input-5-2984f335515a> in <module>
     22   },
     23   body={
---> 24       'values': [df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
     25   }
     26 )

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gspread/client.py in request(self, method, endpoint, params, data, json, files, headers)
     71             return response
     72         else:
---> 73             raise APIError(response)
     74 
     75     def list_spreadsheet_files(self, title=None):

APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Unable to parse range: sheet1!A1', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}'

Comment: It seems weird that the code is not working on your side when in fact it is working on my end. By any chance does your code contain other parts that you have not included in your post? Also have you tried restarting your colab before running?

Comment: The error you have is about parsing the range of spreadsheets, can you try changing the range from `sheet1!A1` to `A1`. Please do let me know if this workaround works on your end

Comment: hello - I'll type everything into a clean coolab plus change the sheet range and let you know